# Elasticsearch Configure Lowercase Tokenizer for Case-Insensitive Kibana Controls Visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7, elasticsearch-analyzers

I've created a Kibana Controls visualization (**Options List** with *Multiselect* and *Dynamic Options* enabled) on my Dashboard. The search only yields results when values are case sensitive. I've [read](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-make-control-visualization-as-not-case-sensitive/218769) that case sensitivity is dependent upon the property's tokenizer during ingest into elasticsearch - which makes sense.

[image: Kibana Controls visualization]

So I've configured my index with the following lowercase tokenizer:

```
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "lowercaseAnalyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  }
...
"mappings": {
  "_source": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "schname": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer":"lowercaseAnalyzer",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    ...
```

When I re-index my data, however, I see no change in the search behavior of the Controls visualization. It's still case sensitive. Could this be because, for `schname`, I'm using a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers)? The Controls Visualization is configured to utilize the `schname.raw` field.

I've also tried tweaking my analyzer to the following with no avail.

```
"tokenizer": "whitespace",
"filter": [ "lowercase" ]
```

Admittedly, this is my first venture into analyzers, so I'm just trying to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it should work on the `schname` field as that is where you put the lower case analyser. if you put it on the `schname.raw` field then you are going to need to use the exact case, as that's what a keyword mapping is - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/keyword.html

there's also an issue around this - https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/50171

Comment: That makes sense, although I only see schname.raw (vs. schname) as an available field for the Control. I wonder if it  is limited to keyword fields?